# Is the category of racks semi-abelian?

Tags: ct.category-theory, quandles, semiabelian-categories

I wonder whether the category of (pointed) racks is [semi-abelian](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-abelian+category).

Any comments and references would be appreciated.

Comment: It has no zero object (the initial object is empty while the terminal object is a singleton). So it's not semi-abelian.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the racks are pointed. So I edited the question. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also there is a big difference between product and coproduct

Comment: Coproduct (also product) exists. And zero object as well. The missing explanations are whether being protomodular and Barr-exact.

Comment: @MarcoFarinati He said *semi-abelian*. So your comment doesn't apply. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semi-abelian+category

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I presume Marco was thinking of the other established meaning of *semi-abelian*, due (as far as I can see) to Palamodov, given [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-abelian_category) and discussed on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272537/are-semi-abelian-categories-in-the-sense-of-palamodov-regular?rq=1).   Palamodov’s sense does require biproducts, so Marco’s comment shows racks aren’t semi-abelian in that sense either.  But it’s clear from Kadir’s second comment that he has the more standard meaning in mind.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Learn something new every day. Thanks! (And now that I look again, the tag [tag:abelian-categories] seems inappropriate. I think I'll remove it. The [tag:semiabelian-categories] tag has a description which matches the one OP meant.)

Answer (score 13):

The category $\mathbf{Rack}$ of racks is Barr-exact since it is a variety of universal algebras, but it is not protomodular. Indeed, the category of sets is equivalent to the category of racks satisfying the identity $a\triangleleft b =a$, so it is a full epireflective subcategory of $\mathbf{Rack}$. In particular, there is an inclusion functor $\mathbf{Set}\to \mathbf{Rack}$ which preserves limits and reflects isomorphisms; then if $\mathbf{Rack}$ was protomodular $\mathbf{Set}$ would also be protomodular, which is false.

I found this argument in the [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-013-9350-7) "A Galois-Theoretic Approach to the Covering Theory of Quandles" by Valérian Even. It also shows that $\mathbf{Rack}$ cannot be Mal'tsev, or even congruence-permutable.