# Ext groups of locally convex topological vector spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Suppose I work over $\mathbb{C}$. Is it known for which locally convex topological vector spaces $V$, we have $\text{Ext}^i(V, \mathbb{C})=\{0\}$ for all $i>0$, working with the type of Ext groups that Wengenroth uses. For instance, is it true when $V$ is Frechet and nuclear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Hahn-Banach theorem implies that $\mathbb C$ is an injective object in the category of complex locally convex topological vector spaces. Therefore, Ext$^i(V,\mathbb C)=0$ for every locally convex space $V$.

Comment: I couldn't remember what "the type of Ext groups that Wengenroth uses" are, I am slightly disappointed that they seem to be what I would have naively assumed ;-)

Comment: I am sorry to disappoint you. The Ext groups were in fact already considered by Palamodov who was the first to use derived functors in the locally convex theory.

Comment: Indeed, back in the days when I was trying to study Banach versions, I had looked at some of the general properties of categories which Palamodov calls semi-abelian, but only for the Banach-space categories https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272537/

Comment: I was aware that Palamodov defined these groups before Wengenroth! I just didn't know how to refer to them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment.